# Window scroll to start when open dialog at the end of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a page with width is over 100% (2000px). When I click to show dialog from button in the end of page (by horizontal page), window scroll to the start of page (by horizontal page) and display the dialog.

[image]

This is my code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQRxGY)

```
$mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('This is an alert title')
        .textContent('You can specify some description text in here.')
        .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
        .ok('Got it!')
        .targetEvent(ev)
    );
  };
```

I use angularjs 1.5 and newest angular material js.

How can i show dialog from button in the end of page (by horizontal page) and window not scroll to the start of page?

Comment: I was testing on Chrome 54.0.2840.99 and it doesn't scroll to the leftmost of the page. The scrollbar doesn't scroll at all. What web browser and which version are you using?

Comment: I updated my question with image. Thanks.
Althought It doesn't scroll to the left but It doesn't show at current position of horizontal page. When I click into button, alert display at the left of the page. I want it displays at the end of the page where current position of page.

Comment: I found a workaround. Check <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222457/angular-1-material-design-scrolls-to-top-after-closing-dialog-in-firefix/46441449#46441449">this</a> out.

Comment: I found a workaround. Check <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222457/angular-1-material-design-scrolls-to-top-after-closing-dialog-in-firefix/46441449#46441449">this</a> out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following CSS.

```
.md-dialog-container {
  width: 2000px;
}

md-backdrop {
  width: 2000px;
}

md-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

It adjusts dialog container's and backdrop's width.
Then, positioning the dialog the way you want.

See a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/attomos/pen/ZByGbg).